# strcasecmp() for utf-8 strings does not work properly (MacOSX, iOS)

Tags: ios, macos, locale

What am I missing?

```
// Excerpt from some .mm source file:
std::set locale(LC_ALL, "ru_RU.UTF-8");
int rv = strcasecmp([@"слово" UTF8String], [@"СЛОВО" UTF8String]);
assert(rv == 0);
```

I expect case insensitive comparison to complete successfully, but in reality I'm gearing non-zero return code from strcasecmp.

Answer (score 0):

The reason `strcasecmp()` does not work is that [it's useless on multibyte strings](https://www.gnu.org/software/libunistring/manual/libunistring.html#char-_002a-strings).

Since it seems you're working with `Objective-C++`:

```
if ([@"слово" caseInsensitiveCompare:@"СЛОВО"] == NSOrderedSame ) {
    // strings are equal except for possibly case
    NSLog(@"matched");
}
```

This should work for case-insensitive matches.

↳ [Searching, Comparing, and Sorting Strings](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/SearchingStrings.html)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I understand (and one can provide dozen ways to overcome) how to do case-insensitive strings comparison in  objc++. I just hoped, that, since current c/c++ standards still lack multibyte string comparison, apple guys silently implemented it in "standard" functions.

Comment: There is `mbscasecmp`, although I don’t know if it’s part of the standard library as of this time.